# How to set value of react hook in promise?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, request, react-hooks

I am getting a data from the promise and I want to set it in react hook, it does but it makes infinite requests and re-rendering of the page, also I want some specific only data to fill

```
const [rows, setRows] = useState([]);
useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
        myEmploiList({
            user: user.id
        }).then((data) => {
            //setRows(data);
            const newData = [];
            data.forEach((item, index) => {
                newData[index] = {
                    id: item._id,
                    name: item.name,
                    society: item.society
                };
                setRows(newData);
            });
        });
    }
    fetchData();
});
```

Comment: Did you read the docs for `useEffect`? If you don't supply the deps array it gets called *every render*.

Comment: Where does myEmploiList and user come from?

Comment: myEmploiList is a request, and user is from the redux store for current user... I will never guess deps Actually I am new in react sorry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should add dependencies to your [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) hook. It is the second argument of this hook.

```
useEffect(() => {
// your code
}, [deps]);
```

deps explanation:

- no value: will execute effect every time your component renders.
- []: will execute effect only the first time the component renders.
- [value1, value2, ...]: will execute effect if any value changes.

For further reading, I highly recommend [this blog post](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/).

Answer (score 0):

Move `setRows` call out of the `forEach` loop and include `user.id` into the dependency array

```js
const [rows, setRows] = useState([]);
useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
        myEmploiList({
            user: user.id
        }).then((data) => {
            //setRows(data);
            const newData = [];
            data.forEach((item, index) => {
                newData[index] = {
                    id: item._id,
                    name: item.name,
                    society: item.society
                };
            });
            setRows(newData);
        });
    }
    fetchData();
}, [user.id]);
```